# Paypal logo not displaying in magento checkout page

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-sandbox

In magento we are using Paypal express checkout.

Right now in the checkout page the payapl image is not loading. Previously it was ok.

This is the image src in page:

```
https://fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&amp;buttontype=ecmark&amp;locale=en_US" alt="Acceptance Mark" class="v-middle
```

Comment: The Paypal logo on our payment types page does not load too, and even it takes 60 seconds before it times out. As a quick fix, I just replaced the image url with a local one, in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`: `_getDynamicImageUrl`: `return '/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/paypal_logo.gif';`

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue currently with the dynamic images, we are currently working to resolve these issues.